# Why compare digital variables in c# is wrong

Tags: c#

The code is written in c#. My condition compares two double variables. In the onePercent variable I have the value 7. ..., and in sizeBuf 2. ... The result of the condition is 2 greater than 7. I don’t understand anything. Maybe someone sees the error?

[image]

Initially, the variables were `float`, but I have changed them to `double`, in the hope that the result would change to the expected one.

Comment: Please 1) translate question to English or post it at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ 2) add code and values as text not images.

Comment: Also - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation. 2 is not greater than 7, but 2E-06 is greater than 7E-09

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the (approximate) values `7.9` and `2.6`, but instead have the values `7.9*10^-9` and `2.6*10^-6`, using the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). So the values are actually:

```
0.0000000079 (onePercent)
0.0000026    (sizeBuf)
```

How you can see that `7.9E-09` is smaller than `2.6E-06`.